# QueryString value with special chars turns into a square in IE

Tags: asp.net, query-string, special-characters, url-encoding

I'm trying to get my head around special chars from a querystring in ASP.NET. In every other browser, this works perfectly: `mysite.com?s=smør`, but in IE it writes the **ø** letter as a square.

I have searched high and low for a solution and read about `Server.UrlEncode()`, but `Server.UrlEncode()` writes this: sm%ef%bf%bdr which isn't very pleasant to read for the user either ;-)

When writing ÆØÅ anywhere on the page, it works perfect, so it must be because it's from the querystring somehow.

My code is as follows:

```
@* Check the searchterm querystring for null or empty value *@
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["s"] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["s"]))
{        
    string searchTerm = Server.UrlEncode(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["s"]);        
    <span>@Server.UrlDecode(searchTerm)</span>
}
```

So, anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

Made a quickfix/hack like this which works:

```
string rawUrl = Server.UrlDecode(HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
string searchTerm = rawUrl.Substring(rawUrl.IndexOf('=') + 1);
```

It's not pretty though ;-)

Comment: have you tried to put <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> ? maybe the oter browsers are auto detecting the charset correctly but not IE.

Comment: Hi aleation, yes I tried with that, but it didn't do anything :-/

Comment: Sorry I didn't read the second part, you should try to Server.UrlDecode() the passed (the encoded one) to get the char again.  dunno if I wrote it correctly as I'm not too much into asp.net but it should be like that. It's normal that you cannot display those kind of chars on the address bar

Comment: Alright, so I have to first Encode and then Decode? :-)

Comment: Yes the encode is to pass over the address bar "safe" characters, in this case, ø is translated into %ef%bf%bd for safe data transaction. Then you use decode to translate %ef%bf%bd to ø again.

Comment: just had a go at it, but it just Decodes it to a square again :-(

Comment: can you paste the specifi codes ?

Comment: Yup, updated my question with code snippet :-)